# How to detect "slot filling" in Watson Assistant response

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I noticed that Watson Assistant's response has no way to detect if slot filling is occurring.  You can see "context" if output context was set according to their example:

```
{
  "output": {
    "generic": [
      {
        "response_type": "text",
        "text": "Hello! What can I do for you?"
      }
    ],
    "intents": [
      {
        "intent": "hello",
        "confidence": 0.9281370162963867
      }
    ],
    "entities": []
  },
  "context": {
    "global": {
      "system": {
        "turn_count": 1,
        "user_id": "55cd47b1-3847-430b-ba28-1739e0654576"
      },
      "session_id": "55cd47b1-3847-430b-ba28-1739e0654576"
    },
    "skills": {
      "main skill": {
        "system": {
          "state": "eyJzZXNzaW9uX2lkIjoiNTVjZDQ3YjEtMzg0Ny00MzBiLWJhMjgtMTczOWUwNjU0NTc2Iiwic2tpbGxfcmVmZXJlbmNlIjoibWFpbiBza2lsbCIsImFzc2lzdGFudF9pZCI6ImViM2RmZGRlLTJkNDUtNDBmYS05NDZlLTk2ODVmNTU2NzhhOSIsImluaXRpYWxpemVkIjp0cnVlLCJkaWFsb2dfc3RhY2siOlt7ImRpYWxvZ19ub2RlIjoicm9vdCJ9XSwibGFzdF9icmFuY2hfbm9kZSI6ImdyZWV0aW5nX29wdGlvbl8zIn0="
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "user_id": "55cd47b1-3847-430b-ba28-1739e0654576"
}
```

However, in the response that comes when slot filling is occurring there is no way to see that there is something similar to open context.

```
{
  "output": {
    "intents": [
      {
        "intent": "action_36417_intent_42985",
        "confidence": 1
      }
    ],
    "entities": [],
    "generic": [
      {
        "response_type": "text",
        "text": "Lite Plan: $10/month and Premium with Tech Support: $99/month."
      }
    ]
  },
  "user_id": "64e28440-84e2-4246-bfad-34daab1b92e5"
}
```

So in this case, you just have to advise the conversation designer to always put output context?

The reason this is important is because I need to detect whether slot filling or open context exists in order to know if the next message should go to the same bot or not.

Comment: I don't understand your question. It seems like you are using the API (or SDK-based API calls). What are you exactly doing and what is the issue?

Comment: I'm using SDK-based API calls.  When I get a response I want to know if slot filling is occurring (this is different than having output context), in services like DialogFlow or Lex you can detect either 1) slot filling or 2) open context.  

It seems in Watson you can only detect if open context is there, and not slot filling.  What I mean by slot filling: When the bot is getting required parameters and goes through a list of questions to ensure it gets all parameters to complete the action.  Perhaps Watson does not call this "slot filling" like other NLUs.

Answer (score 1):

> The reason this is important is because I need to detect whether slot filling or open context exists in order to know if the next message should go to the same bot or not.

I believe this is the crux of your question. As in most implementations multiple skills would not be used in such a fashion. So checking for slot filling is redundant.

For your issue, just have a step that fires after all slots are filled and use that to trigger when to talk to another bot.